# Using rgb instead of Hex in Three.js

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js, rgb

I'd like the background of my three.js project to fade colors as the camera moves, so I want to work in rgb or hsb values instead of hex.

I'm having trouble replacing this line:

```
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, .5);
```

with anything that will allow me to fade the color. I've tried:

```
var r = 255;
var g = 255;
var b = 255; //start them all at white for now
var bgcolor = rgb(r,g,b);
renderer.setClearColor(bgcolor, .5); //50% opacity
```

Comment: r, g, and b are betweeen 0 and 1.  http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Color

Comment: I also wanted to add that Three.js is interpreting this as a string, so I needed to do this:
renderer.setClearColor("rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")",1);